# How to get rid of paper-menu-button first item highlight in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I'm trying to get rid of paper-menu-button first item being selected, because when I'm press menu button and paper-menu drops down there always are first item highlighted (not selected but highlighted with gray color). Is there any workaround to disable that auto highlight function? Property (focused="false") not working and by default it's false.

```
<paper-menu-button vertical-offset="42" horizontal-align="right">
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing I've found a solution, don't know does my solution affects any "deep" functions but while I'm tested everything worked fine. So to get rid of auto highlight first item in paper-menu-button or paper-dropdown-menu add folowing.

```
<paper-menu-button>
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
<div class="dropdown-content"></div>
<paper-menu class="dropdown-content" tabindex="0">
<paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
<paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
</paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

So as in code shown you have to add before dropdown content an empty div with same class and to dropdown content add tabindex. If someone will find any bug this solution causes just reply here and I will try find a different solution.